# Break inside on click alert

Tags: php, onclick

I have a button-field with an alert before it's been executed. That "onclick" alert code containts a text. I can't make brakes inside the text. How can I fix that? I've found [this question][1] but I still couldn't fix it. The problem is that nothing happens at all when I click the button.

```html
echo "<tr><td><strong>
<form action='respondent.php' method='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$row['rid']."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='firstname' value='".$row['firstname']."'> 
<a href='respondent.php'><button>".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."</button></a>

 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Select'>
 </form>
 </strong></td> 
 
 <td>".$row['email']."</td> 
 <td>".$row['pointsummary']."</td> 
 <td>".$row['datetime']."</td>
 
<td> 
<input type='button' action='deleterespondent.php' value='Delete' 
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you \n want to delete?');">
</td>
</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `single quotes` ' around `\n`

**Code:**

```
<input type='button' action='deleterespondent.php' value='Delete' 
onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you \\n want to delete?');\">
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: It's not possible @Max : When you keep backslash, it was not working. When i removed backslash. It worked. Let, i'm showing you screenshot.

Comment: Sorry it did something wrong and now I've done what you said. I get this error-message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting ',' or ';' "

Comment: Are you using any echo out there @Max ? Please paste 2-3 lines of code above to this button.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense but the code is inside an echo.

Comment: Then, why you send without echo . Send whole code @Max. It will make sense.

Comment: Yes I juse echo. I will in 2 minutes update the question with more code then.

Comment: I have now updated my question and added the whole code.

Comment: And, Please let me know what happened @Max

Comment: Thanks for that. Done.

Comment: Glad. I helped you Mr @Max

Answer (score 1):

use `\n` this way `confirm('Are you sure you \n want to delete?');`
\n is used within a string so no need to use `'Are you sure you '\n' want to delete?'`

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/b95yrrwu/

Comment: I get this error-message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting ',' or ';' "

Comment: can you post some code snippet so we can see the issue and have you matched your code with the demo https://jsfiddle.net/b95yrrwu/

Comment: Plus one Brother. Nice One. :)